# Python MySQLdb cursor executemany on massive insert not working

Tags: python, mysql, dictionary, executemany

I am working on a Python script that reads data from a big excel file and stores the necessary data on corresponding dictionary variables.

Once all of the file's data is read and processed, the script iterates through all the dictionaries by 100 records and calls on a function that will insert them to a table using the executemany function.

The thing is, there are some records that are NOT being inserted to a specific table, which means there are more tables that are not inserting properly, even though I see the data is being passed.
Ex: record ID: IH1-01-01 is taken into consideration to be inserted but it doesn't in the end.
I don't see any fatal errors or anything that points to this mishap happening.

What else could be causing these records to not be inserted?

Here's part of the code for your review

```
#function that doesn't work properly
def InsertarAnaquelPisoLetraMasivo(queryAnaquel):
try:
    query = "INSERT INTO  Anaquel(anaq_id,anaq_nombre,anaq_piso, anaq_letra, anaq_cantidad,anaq_movimiento, anaq_almacen) VALUES (NULL,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, 'Mex')"
    cursor.executemany(query, queryAnaquel)
#added so I can see what data was being passed
#I can confirm all records are there but don't get inserted for some reason
    for line in queryAnaquel:
        print line
except:
    print ("Error ",  sys.exc_info()[0])

#iterate through excel file
for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
#...
#read item's location   
ubicacion = sheet['H' + str(row)].value if sheet['H' + str(row)].value is not None else ""

if revisarSiLlaveEsConsiderada(ubicaciones, ubicacion):
    ubicaciones[ubicacion] += 1
else:
    ubicaciones[ubicacion] = 1
    

#part that processes data and calls for insert
print "Configurando anaqueles"
for key in ubicaciones:
ubicacionSplit = key.split("-")
tipoAnaquel = "Alto"

if len(ubicacionSplit) > 2:
    tipoAnaquel = "Isla"
    pis = ubicacionSplit[1]
    let = ubicacionSplit[2]
elif len(ubicacionSplit)==1:
    pis = ''
    let = ''
else:
    pisoLe = ubicacionSplit[1]
    if len(pisoLe) >1:
        if len(pisoLe) == 2:
            pis = pisoLe[0]
            let = pisoLe[1]
        else:
            pis = pisoLe
            let = ''
    else:
        pis = pisoLe
        let = ''
        
ubs = ubicacionSplit[0]
cantidad = ubicaciones[key]

detalleAnaquel = detalleUbicacion(ubs, pis, let)
if detalleAnaquel == "":
#Here's where to look
    value = (ubs,pis, let, cantidad, tipoAnaquel)
    queryAnaquel.append(value)
    if cuentaQueryAnaquel == 100:
        InsertarAnaquelPisoLetraMasivo(queryAnaquel)
        cuentaQueryAnaquel = 1
        queryAnaquel = []
    else:
        cuentaQueryAnaquel += 1
else:
    idAnaquel = detalleAnaquel
    updateAnaquel(idAnaquel, cantidad)

#In case we haven't reached 100 after iterating through all recordds        
if len(queryAnaquel) > 0:
  InsertarAnaquelPisoLetraMasivo(queryAnaquel)
  queryAnaquel = []
  cuentaQueryAnaquel=1
```

Table's config:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Anaquel` (
`anaq_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`anaq_nombre` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`anaq_movimiento` enum('Alto','Mediano','Bajo','Caja','Isla','') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Bajo',
`anaq_piso` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`anaq_letra` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
`anaq_cantidad` int(11) NOT NULL,
`anaq_capacidad` int(1) NOT NULL,
`anaq_almacen` enum('Mex','Usa') NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`anaq_id`),
KEY `anaq_nombre` (`anaq_nombre`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=26701 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Problem data, as was printed by command prompt:
(u'IH1', u'1', u'4', 38, 'Isla')

Edit: I previously removed warnings on the script and I just commented out the call on the warning removal.

I see a lot of warnings that say something like this:

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py:206: Warning: Incorrect string value: '\xCC\x81s qu...' for column 'booName_title' at row 1
  r = r + self.execute(query, a)
```

Comment: could it be that your data length is not a % of 100? So at the end in the worst case the last 99 Records will not be inserted, because the counter never reaches 100 again?

Comment: @Kartoffelkultur that was already taken into consideration, please see edited code. Sorry about that

Comment: you only call insertar when this condition is met `if cuentaQueryAnaquel == 100:` but dies it reach actually a 100

Comment: Can you please post the crate Statement of the table and an example of an dict that was inserted and one that was not ?

Comment: @Kartoffelkultur Added requested code, let me find the requested info

Comment: Thanks, and could you pls post your code with the edit in the **exact** format (Indentation) as in the real program (copy/paste). As this code is misaligned and in python this could by one error source

Comment: @Kartoffelkultur Ah, shoot. Sorry man. Indented it, if there's anything else that doesn't look good please let me know

Comment: See, your `for key in ubicaciones:` should be followed by an indentation, and you should get an error like `expected an indented block`. Please simply copy paste. Otherwise we can not try the code ourself. There are multiple such errors, so when you just fix ist here it makes everything more complicated.

Comment: Sorry for the waste of time, I just edited my post with new info

Comment: No problem, its just takes longer bevor someone can help ;) Can you pls reduce the code to a working minimum that reproduces the problem? Like array of two example dicts, one that is inserted successfully and one that is not inserted. So we can run the code and try ourselves, because there are still many problem with Indentation and I don't see any obvious problem. But most of the time I have to run the code my self to see the stupid obvious problems.